# Homework Question: Moments

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, statics

Can someone please explain this question?[image]

My work:

If we take B to be the pivot then as B gets closer to mg the torque due to mg gets smaller, but I don't really see how this affects the **force** F (I can only think about how this might affect the torque by F)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I apologize for this. This is not a homework problem. It's just a conceptual thing I couldn't understand. I didn't know where else to place this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order the beam to stay still, you must have balanced forces and torques. So if the distance from the point that mg is acting and the reaction in point B is getting smaller , the net force (reaction) in support B is getting bigger in order to have the torques balanced.
This way the force in point A is obviously getting smaller.

Comment: What do you consider to be the pivot here?

Comment: I edit my answer. Notice that$Fa$ plus $Fb$ must equal $mg$.

Comment: Any point but the easiest is to get the point that mg is acting.

Comment: I understand your reasoning! However what if we consider B to be the pivot?

Comment: The reaction in point A is getting smaller. If Sa is the distance from point A to the point that mg is acting and Sb the distance from point B, then FaxSa must equal FbxSb. Notice that Fa plus Fb is equal to mg so if you make the substitution in the system of these equations you will get the answer.

Comment: Same result if you take as pivot point B , in fact any point of the beam, but it is a little bit more complicated to do the calculations.

Comment: But I am a bit confused specifically about taking B as the pivot... How does that give me an expression for F?

Comment: I'm writing this answer from my cell phone so i can't send you a diagram.But think that in order to have the beam balanced ,forces and torques in any point of the beam must be balanced. In your case Fa plus Fb equal mg (balanced forces).I you take point B as pivot then about the torques must have FaxSab equals mgxSb. If you the substitution to this system of equations you will get the same result.